# ¿por que me arroja este error : Missing expression after unary operator '-'.?

Tags: python, django, framework

estoy iniciándome en `django` y estoy intentando crear mi primer archivo pero no he tenido éxito debido a que al introducir el código `" - admin starproject p"` que lo uso para poder crear una subcarpeta dentro de la carpeta principal no me lo permite por el error que es este :
--- Missing expression after unary operator '-' ---

Si pueden ayudarme y así yo poder iniciar con `django` se los agradezco

> PS C:\Users\ricar\OneDrive\Escritorio\archivosDjangoPython> - admin
> starproject p ParserError: Line |    1 |  - admin starproject p
> |   ~
> | Missing expression after unary operator '-'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nunca pongas código o mensajes de error como imagen, pues dependiendo del dispositivo de la persona que lo lea, puede verse tan pequeño que resulte ilegible. Mejorarás tus oportunidades de ser respondido si pegas esos mensajes como texto. Por otro lado parece que el problema no es ni de python ni de django, sino del uso de la terminal. Quita el -  delante de admin.

Comment: gracias por lñas recomendaciones , ya hice lo que me dijo y no pude solventar la situacion de error

Comment: Siempre es buena idea leer los errores o traducirlos si no los entiendes. Te ayudarán a saber qué está mal. En este caso te dice que hay un problema con el `-` y la expresión que le sigue.